# Drupal 6 site re-indexing not happening

Tags: drupal, cron, drupal-6, reindex

I am working on a Drupal 6 site.

Facing an issue: Site Re-Indexing not working.

Even if after running the cron successfully.

I have already gone through google search and Drupal forums.

Can somebody please guide me?

Comment: Try disabling modules and then indexing. Maybe some module is causing this. Other way, check the error logs. Drupal one, but also php error log.

Comment: Thanks @MilanG, I will try it and let you know.